# How to manage sessions with Firebase Authentication, React SPA and Django Rest Framework Backend?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, session, firebase-authentication, single-page-application

I think the most important details are in the title. I'm well aware that this combination is mostly not recommended. Therefore I would be very happy if someone might come up with an alternative way of solving the detailed problem that follows:

The SPA and the Backend-API are running on different hosts provided by Google Cloud Services (Flexible Google App Engine).

We have a user account that is supposed to run on several devices. One device will be used as day-to-day operations in a store by the manager. When the store owner (who might be different from the manager) wants to change Store-Properties he should be able to login on a different device and request a TAN for an admin session. With Firebase Custom Claims we can make the admin session available to the account, but this would mean that the store manager can also access the properties in the current session. This shouldn't be possible. That's why we need a session-based management of user access.

The only option I see this far is having Django assigning sessions, which means we have to mess with CORS and reduce Django's security measures. The resources available to me generally and on Google are sadly not deep enough. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why is it not recommended though?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use OAuth2 authentication that can be easily implemented in Django by using certain libraries. Tokens will be generated from the backend and the SPA can safely use these tokens as cookies or in the headers on every request sent back to the backend or Django REST in this case.

There will be some settings like the ones you mentioned as CORS. There are already libraries that can lift the heavy weight for you. You will only need to go through some settings and black list or whitelist specific ips or domains. Wildcards can also be used too.

**Django Libraries:**

Django Rest: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Django OAuth2 authentication:
https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Django CORS Headers:
https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

**SPA:**

The following are certain notes that will save you some time in the future regarding front end http requests.

X-CSRFToken: < csrf token >

X-Requested-Width: "XMLHttpRequest"

Authorization: < Oauth2 Token > // 'Bearer ***************************************'

ES6 Example:

```
  (async () =>{
       let headers = {
         "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
         "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
         "Authorization": oAuth2Token
        };

        const data = await fetch(url, {
           method: "GET",
           mode: "cors",
           headers: headers,
           credentials: "same-origin",
        });

        let dataJson = await data.json();

        console.log(dataJson) // prints data returned from DJANGO REST API
  })()
```

Note:

Another route you can take is to use Django as the only backend used by the SPA and connect to firebase via Django. That way the SPA will only work with one backend (Django), where this backend is taking care of any Firebase or any other 3 party operation

Comment: Thank you very much! Will this work when the Authorization-Header is already populated with the Firebase JWT-Token or will I have to define a custom header for this?

Comment: Well your SPA must be able to change the request based on the endpoint. For example, requests meant for Django REST API must have "X-Requested-Width" in the headers; Now firebase won't required that specific header, it may requests others so basically the SPA must be able to change the header, URL and body of the request depending on the system that is trying to connect.